# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting USE_I18N, but settings are not configured

Tags: python, django, mysql-python

I want to connect MySQL database to my django project, but it is throwing an error :

> "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting
>   USE_I18N, but settings are not configured. You must either define the
>   environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
>   settings.configure() before accessing settings."

**Trace:**

```
 (myenv) LIBINGLADWINs-MacBook-Air:libinrenold$ django-admin dbshell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/libinrenold/Desktop/djangoworks/myenv/bin/django-admin", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/Users/libinrenold/Desktop/djangoworks/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/libinrenold/Desktop/djangoworks/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/libinrenold/Desktop/djangoworks/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/libinrenold/Desktop/djangoworks/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 322, in execute
    saved_locale = translation.get_language()
  File "/Users/libinrenold/Desktop/djangoworks/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 195, in get_language
    return _trans.get_language()
  File "/Users/libinrenold/Desktop/djangoworks/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 59, in __getattr__
    if settings.USE_I18N:
  File "/Users/libinrenold/Desktop/djangoworks/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/libinrenold/Desktop/djangoworks/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 39, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting USE_I18N, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

**settings.py**.

```
  DATABASES = {
        'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST':'',
        'PORT': '',
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You must define the relevant variable to show where your `settings.py` file lives:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
```

This is the relevant [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#envvar-DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE) entry:

> When you use Django, you have to tell it which settings you’re using.
> Do this by using an environment variable, DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.
>
> The value of DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE should be in Python path syntax,
> e.g. mysite.settings. Note that the settings module should be on the
> Python import search path.

If you are using a [virtualenv](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtualenv/) (which is the best practice), you can paste the relevant `export` command in the file `<path-to-virtualenv>/bin/activate`

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. I'm just a rookie, i always use virtualenv, now im getting the below error..

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'couzinz' -------------- but ive have added "import sys
sys.path.append("/Users/../mysite")"

Comment: @reno_libiii Please accept an answer since this question is answered and upvote the answers that gave you a good hint. Your comment introduces the need for another new question where you can paste the complete error message.

Comment: What if you are just querying a database?  I don't have a 'mysite' other then the REST I am querying

Comment: @BrianWiley "mysite" is actually the `<project_name>`. The directory structure is `<project_name>/<project_name>/settings.py`. This in python should be exported as: `project_name.settings` because `./manage.py` lies under the first `<project_name>`.

Answer (score 18):

I had this problem because I tried to import a django script after just typing

```
python
```

instead of

```
python manage.py shell
```

Duh!

Comment: Yep, my brain was off too and I was thinking it was something more complicated. Thanks for pointing this one out!

Comment: Thanks, I spent too long racking my brain on this. I used `django-admin makemigrations users` instead of `python manage.py makemigrations users`

Comment: Thanks! Typing unconciously `python` by habit then it became a blind spot until someone points it out.

Answer (score 17):

It happens to me too, I just now found unintentional.

I changed "configuration" in top of PyCharm IDE so pycharm confused when try to run django code. Exactly the problem popup when I try to run server with shortcut but when I used terminal to run server, I found django code not having any problem and pycharm can't found setting.

So please check "configuration" in top pycharm's ide maybe you do same mistake :)

I'm new in django so be calm if my answer was silly.

[image: configuration picture]

Answer (score 6):

### Problem

I had the same error with Django==3.2 and djangorestframework==3.12.4 (2021/04) when I ran unittest. In my case, the `python manage.py test` works properly but I cannot directly run or debug the test module which was in a specific app, and I get this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

### Solution

First I added the django project root to the `sys.path`. Then I added `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to the environment variable to address the project setting root and called the Django `setup` function. This is my code:

```
from os import path, environ
from sys import path as sys_path
from django import setup

sys_path.append(<path to django setting.py>)    
environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django_project.settings')
setup()
```

Answer (score 5):

put this in top of settings.py 
this will configure django for you

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", __file__)
import django
django.setup()
```

Comment: This will not solve OP issue as the settings file is not "found" by the django-admin script

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error with Django 3.0.8 (july 2020) when trying to run the server, and in my case no need for the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable. The solution is to use another form to run the server:

```
cd <directory containing manage.py>
python3 manage.py runserver
```

It works to run Django shell too :

```
python3 manage.py shell
```

Answer (score 3):

Like raratiru answered, you need `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable defined with the relative pythonic path to your setting file.

OR use your [`django-admin` command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-and-manage-py) with the `settings` parameter:

```
django-admin --settings=mysite.settings dbshell
```

Comment: now im getting a error as ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'

Comment: You'll need to replace `mysite` with the name of your project/folder where the settings file is in :) ! Maybe it's `djangoworks` looking from your post!?

Comment: the command should look like `django-admin dbshell --settings mysite.settings` to be accepted from the interpreter, see the link: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-and-manage-py) django-admin command and `$ django-admin help dbshell`

Answer (score 0):

Below code in terminal to manually inform which settings I am using worked for me:

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear all I faced the same problem and i scrapped the web to find a solution. None of the one above solved anything.

The issue in my case was related to a wrong configuration of pycharm. As for someone above the app didnt have any issue when launched from the command line/ shell.

The issue is here:

[image]

For some reason the env variable disappeared. i added back and everything started to work again without any issue.