# Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to debug url.py in my project but i got this error all the time, I tried almost everything, any ideas?
Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting USE\_I18N, but settings are not configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700347/django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-requested-setting-use-i18n-but-set)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37258313/16236218). You need to tell Python where your Django project is located. You cannot simply run the urls.py script as it is a part of your whole Django Project ecosystem and it is dependent on the configurations. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

1.Ensure that the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable is set correctly. It should point to the Python module that contains your Django settings. For example, if your settings module is named myproject.settings, you would set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to "myproject.settings". Double-check the correctness of this variable in your development environment.

2.Make sure you have imported and called the settings.configure() function before accessing the settings. This function initializes the Django settings using default values or those specified by you. Place the settings.configure() function at the beginning of your script, preferably before importing any other Django-related modules. For example:If you have already included the settings.configure() call and are still encountering the error, verify that it is placed before importing any other Django-related modules.

3.Verify that your Django project structure is set up correctly. The url.py file should be located within a Django project, and the project's root directory should be in the Python module search path.

4.Double-check that you have installed Django and any required dependencies in your environment. Ensure that the correct versions of Django and its dependencies are installed.